# MySQL Regex Only Show Matched Portion

Tags: mysql, regex

I've been trying to find a way with MySQL's REGEXP function to return only a portion of a matched row.

I am doing:
SELECT * FROM table WHERE text REGEXP "[.*]cat[.*]"

The text itself is very long (had to use LONGTEXT field to fit it in the table). So I only want to display

cat

Is there a way I can make it so it only displays the matching text, and not the entire text field?

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer. Using MySQL UDF PREG.

https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg

I had a hard time installing this on my redhat server. I followed these steps:

https://gist.github.com/kamermans/1658660 (incase that page goes away, here are the steps:)

```
yum -y install pcre-devel gcc make automake mysql-devel
```

this file was not avialable. I just googled for the filename and found it online.

```
wget http://www.mysqludf.org/lib_mysqludf_preg/lib_mysqludf_preg-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

The rest of these steps should work as listed below:

```
tar -zxvf lib_mysqludf_preg-1.0.1.tar.gz
cd lib_mysqludf_preg-1.0.1
./configure
make install
echo "You'll need to enter your MySQL password a few times to install the UDFs and test them"
mysql -u root-p < installdb.sql
make test
```

Answer (score -2):

Per your comment:

Now that I understand what you need to do, the answer is, this doesn't exist in MySQL. MySQL is not a language for parsing lengthy text files. You need to write a Perl script that connects to MySQL, or use some other general-purpose language, to do the parsing.

So the answer is no.

---

There's no way to show the matching text, and even that doesn't make sense. If the `text` column is really that long, you don't have to grab it in your `select` query.

Or you could do something like the [MySQL substring function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring), to grab only the first n characters.

`select substring(text, 0, 10) from table where text like '%cat%';`

You don't need to use the REGEXP function here. You can just use the `like` operator as shown above.

Comment: Obviously this is a simplified example of what I'm trying to do. I am parsing some log files which are hundreds of lines. If a pattern is found, I just want to verify the pattern matched properly. I am trying to avoid having to look through the entire entry, which, as I stated before, is hundreds of lines long.